# nodejs app running pigpio - error Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid

Tags: raspbian, pigpio

I am trying to run my Nodejs app but keep getting error: initInitialise Cant lock /var/run/pigpio.pid. I tired remove the the file with rm /var/run/pigpio.pid but the error remains. I have read tons of forms about removing the pigpio.pid file and that I probably have another process running. After hours of searching and testing commands I manage to temporally fix it; meaning once the raspberry pi reboots back to constant error. After removing the pigpio.pid file I ran sudo pigpiod. The console reads initInitialise bind to port 888 failed address already in use cant initialise pigpio liabry. I learned afterwards there was some failed process running on port 8888. I shutdowned the process with kill -9. Ran sudo pigpiod again then woosh my application runs. How do fix this issue? It appears I have some failed process running on port 8888.

My application was running fine until I accidentally ftp files wihile the node process was running on server. After that was when pigpio started erroring.

Any input on what might be happening?

Comment: Here is a link that kind of address the issue I am having wih port 8888 however I does not purpose a fix. - https://github.com/fivdi/pigpio/issues/7

Comment: I ran these commands to figure find and kill the prcoess running on port 8888 :   
sudo apt-get install lsof
sudo lsof -i TCP:8888

Comment: Running sudo lsof -i TCP:8888 shows me the old application running port 8888. When I kill the port with sudo kill -9 pid, the port just re-spawns again.

Comment: And how come when I reboot the pi the port is not automatically cleared?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=76559

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I need to completely reinstall npm and pm2. Every thing works great now.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on the left side. This will finish the question and it will not pop up again.